# Calculate $\frac{2}{\alpha^2}-\frac{1}{(\alpha +1)^2}$ if $\alpha$ be a root of $x^2+(1-\sqrt3)x+1-\sqrt3=0$

Tags: calculus, roots, quadratics

If $\alpha$ is a root of $x^2+(1-\sqrt3)x+1-\sqrt3=0$ calculate

$$\frac{2}{\alpha^2}-\frac{1}{(\alpha +1)^2}$$
What I have done:
$$\begin{aligned}
\alpha^2+\alpha+1&=\sqrt3(\alpha+1)\\
&\implies\alpha^4+2\alpha^3+3\alpha^2+2\alpha+1=3\alpha^2+6\alpha+3\\
&\implies\alpha^2(\alpha+1)^2=\alpha^2+4\alpha+2\\
&\implies\frac{2}{\alpha^2}-\frac{1}{(\alpha +1)^2}=1
\end{aligned} $$

Is there any easy way to calculate?

Comment: It is not obvious to me how did you get rid of the square root. in 2nd step?

Comment: @NoChance by squaring both sides

Comment: OK, thank you for your answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another way (not necessarily easier than OP’s one).

$\sqrt3(\alpha+1)=\alpha(\alpha+1)+1$

$\dfrac{\sqrt3}{\alpha}=1+\dfrac1{\alpha(\alpha+1)}$

$\left(\dfrac{\sqrt3}{\alpha}\right)^2=\left(1+\dfrac1\alpha-\dfrac1{\alpha+1}\right)^2$

$\dfrac3{\alpha^2}=1+\dfrac1{\alpha^2}+\dfrac1{(\alpha+1)^2}\;\;$ (by simplifying twice products)

$\dfrac2{\alpha^2}-\dfrac1{(\alpha+1)^2}=1$